# Queue implementation of file monitoring and send them to a web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, queue, implementation

I need to write an application that will monitor a specific folder for new files created by a 3rd party software, then copy them to my repository and send them, one by one, to a web service. Once the file sent, it will be deleted from the repo.

I will obviously use the FileSystemWatcher for file monitoring and copy them to my repo.
Then i will Enqueue copied file names to the Queue.

What should i do from here?
How do i manage this Queue and Dequeue when file was sent?
Another question is how to make this thread-safe, since the Queue is being accessed from different theads (FileSystemWatcher)?

What is the best and safest way to implement this?

Thanks for you answers,
SkyFox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning:

```
BlockingCollection<string> q = new BlockingCollection<string>();
var bg = new BackgroundWorker();
bg.DoWork += (s,e) => SendFilesToServer();
bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```

In the file watcher event (file created):

```
q.Add(fileName);
```

the 'worker':

```
void SendFilesToServer()
{
    string filename;
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            while (q.TryTake(out fileName))
            {
                // Send to the webservice
            }
            while(q.IsEmpty)
                Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need multiple threads for multiple file watchers. (Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your statement.)  Also, I'm not sure why you even need a queue.

Have you application main thread run the file watcher.  As the file watcher events are fired, you can start the worker threads to handle each file operation to do the actual work involved (one thread per file).  The threaded operations are independent of each other so you don't need to worry about thread safety.  The watcher should be handling the isolation of the file system notification events such that you don't end up with two notification events with the same file.

Comment: Thanks for answer Peter.
My problem begins with transferring the files to a web service, one by one.
That's why i was thinking of queue, to pile them up (the transfer is slow). 
But here is the issue:
i may have several files queued already, more coming from file watcher and some are removed from queue after upload.
How should i manage this logic?